# How do I create new object while changing cards in CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, object, cardlayout

Currently I'm using CardLayout to jump between different guis in my game (main menu, settings, scoreboard etc.):

```
    static JPanel panels = new JPanel();
    static CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    panels.setLayout(cl);
    panels.add(new Menu(), "menu");
    panels.add(new Game(), "game");
    panels.add(new Scoreboard(), "scoreboard");
    panels.add(new Settings(), "settings");
    panels.add(new Info(), "info");
```

and then in the same class I got static method that allows me to jump between game's JComponents (Menu, Game, Scoreboard, Settings, Info).

```
public static void changePanel(String panel){
    cl.show(panels, panel);
}
```

Unfortunately all of those objects are created at the start of the game. 
I need to create new object each time when card is changed and delete old object to save memory. Is that passable?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to call System.gc() which simply is a hint to the garbage collector that you want it to do a collection. There is no way to force an immediate collection though as the garbage collector is non-deterministic.